# NullPointerException when using BufferedWriter with Gdx.files.internal()

Tags: libgdx, java-io

I am trying to write a simple function that saves my player's profile to an internal file but it throws a NullPointerException at the outputWriter initialization.

```
    public void saveProfile(String filePath){
    BufferedWriter outputWriter;
    try{
        outputWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(Gdx.files.local(filePath).write(false)));

        saveInfo[pid]=count;
        gamesLost=saveInfo[pgamesLost]=gamesLost;
        gamesWon=saveInfo[pgamesWon]=gamesWon;
        saveName=name;

        outputWriter.write(name+"\n");
        for(int i=0;i<saveInfo.length;i++){
            outputWriter.write(Integer.toString(saveInfo[i])+"\n");
        }

        outputWriter.close();

    }catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Clearly the result of `Gdx.files.local(filePath)` is null.

Comment: ^ this. For future reference: It might help you to assign each value (e.g. Gdx.files.local,...) to their own variables. Gives more insight when debugging.

Comment: Just to let you know: Internal files are always read only, so you can't write with the `Gdx.files.internal` `FileHandle`. For player profiles etc. you may use `Preference`s, which are the only way to write persistent data when your application is run in the browser.